# How to know what;s going to compile in this situation?

Tags: c++

I have this problem in particular which I don't know why is 30 the answer,

```
int h(int x) {
    if (x < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return x + h(x - 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    cout << 2 * h(5);
    return 0;
}
```

30, is the result, but I don't know why.

Comment: Did you try working it out by hand?  If you did what did you get?

Comment: 2*(5+4+3+2+1). Just take a piece of paper.

Comment: It will become clear, if you just imagine how the program would execute :)

Comment: What did you expect to get instead?

Comment: Just run your program in debug mode, step through line by line ans see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Because:

```
h(5) = 5 + h(4) 
     = 5 + 4 + h(3) 
     = 5 + 4 + 3 + h(2) 
     = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + h(1) 
     = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + h(0) 
     = 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 
     = 15
```

and you print `2 * h(5)` = `2 * 15` = `30`

If you cannot understand just reading the code I encourage you to use a debugger to see the execution, or to add *printf* to trace it

P.S. as you know there is a faster way :

```
int h(int x) {
  return (x < 1) ? 0 
                 : (x*(x+1))/2;
}
```